# Are smart contracts meant to be "updateable"? Is it up to the creator to secure whatever terminal or codes are necessary to update the contract?

Tags: cryptocurrency, contracts

I'm looking into creating a smart contract on Ethereum or Solana, just for fun for now. I know in practice how to create a smart contract, but at this point I have a dilemma:

- In the one hand, it would be wise to be able to fix any potential problems by updating the smart contract
- On the other hand, the setup I used to create the smart contract in the first place (or the passwords, rather, since I'm pretty sure it's not tied to a specific machine) would be vulnerable to hackers or thieves (somehow).

So which is it: are smart contracts set in stone, or is it up to the creator to protect the means they have to update the contract from misuse? How is that done typically?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about personal finance.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be much of a contract if someone could just change it, would it?

To allow updating, sometimes a proxy contract is used. A proxy contract forwards all its calls to another contract, and also allows the owner to change which contract it forwards to. Therefore, the owner can deploy a new contract and redirect the proxy contract (which doesn't change) to the new contract.

You should be wary of these because the owner can take the money and run.

Other times, everyone agrees the old contract is messed up, so they just abandon it and use a new contract.

By analogy, you can't just change a paper contract if you find a mistake in it - if the contract doesn't have a clause saying you can change it, then you write a new one and everyone involed has to sign that one. (This is a little bit messier with paper contracts because a court can rule that you can change it, even if the contract doesn't say you can)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. But how do you use a new contract without changing tokens?

Comment: @MisterMystère You don't. If you change the token, it's a different token. You could write a proxy contract but you probably shouldn't use a token that's a proxy contract, because the owner can take the money and run. *If you change the contract, everyone has to "sign" it again.*

Comment: Whether a contract between two parties is 'on paper' or 'on the blockchain', both are subject to rule of law. The reason that you might think that courts apply on 'paper contracts' but not 'blockchain contracts' is because the pseudo-anonymity of crypto contracts means that outright theft is common and hard to pursue for damages.

Answer (score 2):

Smart contracts are immutable, means once they are deployed to the blockchain, it's almost impossible to change them. If you want to update the contract, you have to program and deploy another one. That is why it's so important for smart contract developers to test their smart contract on testnets before deploying to the mainnet, follow best practices and security designs, and check code for known attack patterns.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. But how do you use a new contract without changing tokens?